# Detect the corners of a grid using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, hough-transform

So I'm currently working on a project(not school related or anything) and a part of it involves being able to detect and project a grid in a picture onto a square image so we can get rid of any skewing the image may have and things alike. My problem now is that I cannot determine what points within my image are the corners of my grid. I have tried using a Hough transform but the problem with that is that many lines are generated, including the grid lines and thus it would be hard to determine which of the detected lines are the edges of the grid automatically. I also tried using a contour detector which gives a similar problem, although its more accurate in tracing out the edges of the grid. I'm unable to pick out what contours belong to the edge of the grid and what contours are say grid lines or just miscellaneous

A screenshot of the results from the Hough transform:

[image: A screenshot of the results from the Hough transform]

and A screenshot of the result from the contour detection:

[image: A screenshot of the result from the contour detection].

Thanks for any help or advice in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to look through the contours and find the largest 4 sided one to grab the outside of your grid.

You would use something like this helper function (processed is my preprocessed image):

```
def largest_4_sided_contour(processed, show_contours=False):
    _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(
        processed, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Sort the contours by area

```
    contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
```

look at the biggest 5 (if there are more than 5, otherwise just look at all of them)

```
    for cnt in contours[:min(5, len(contours))]:
```

If the number of sides is about 4, that's the one we are looking for so we can stop looking and return that one.

```
        if len(approx(cnt)) == 4:
            return cnt
    return None
```

There are some irregularities to your grid so you may have to do some preprocessing or look for a range of the number of sides but generally, by looking at the area of the contour and narrowing down by the number of sides, you should be able to figure something out.

You mentioned getting the corners so this is that step:

```
def get_rectangle_corners(cnt):
    ''' gets corners from a contour '''

    pts = cnt.reshape(cnt.shape[0], 2)
    rect = np.zeros((4, 2), dtype="float32")

    # the top-left point has the smallest sum whereas the
    # bottom-right has the largest sum
    s = pts.sum(axis=1)
    rect[0] = pts[np.argmin(s)]
    rect[2] = pts[np.argmax(s)]

    # compute the difference between the points -- the top-right
    # will have the minumum difference and the bottom-left will
    # have the maximum difference
    diff = np.diff(pts, axis=1)
    rect[1] = pts[np.argmin(diff)]
    rect[3] = pts[np.argmax(diff)]
    return rect
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. I'm not very familiar with python so i was wondering what the purposes of 'show_contours = False' and 'reverse =  True' are

Comment: `Reverse = True` is to sort  biggest to smallest, "z to a" rather than "a to z"

Comment: The other one is the function I grabbed this from had an option to display the image and I forgot to remove that parameter

Comment: Hey, I was wondering why having a size of 4 indicates that that is one of the contours we're looking for? I have printed out all the sizes I get for all my images and none of the have been equal to four. What does size indicate? Sorry for the somewhat trivial questions it's just a bit hard to understand all the pieces being used without looking up what types are being stored and the kind of object storing them.

Comment: I was referring to the number of sides/vertices on the contour. If you have the contour of a rectangle it will be about 4 vertices but it can be more if it is irregular.

Comment: Oh okay that is what I assumed it was, but from the results i'm getting, I have extremely irregular contours maybe?? I mainly get values in the hundreds as my size. I wonder if that is because the contours are drawn with points as opposed to being continuous lines. I'm confused as to why that is the case even though we're using CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE which should only give us the points at the corners.

Comment: Draw the contours one at a time and look at them to figure out what is happening. If you have control of the board, it may be easier to make your grid more regular than to improve the code. Computer vision is an advanced topic. Hopefully my answer was useful to you but it is not meant to solve everything but rather to give a starting point.